# what's a good tool to view the full http request/response in a bridged situation?

Tags: networking

I'm working with an embedded device that's generating HTTP requests to a server in the cloud; I'd like a good way of sitting in between those devices and seeing a full request response cycle.

I thought about using tcpdump or a proxy server of some kind to watch the traffic but am at a bit of a loss as to what the best way to view the request/response un-altered rather than individual TCP packets.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

[Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) is smart enough to assemble the TCP conversation into http chatter if that is an option for you?

Or maybe you could proxy through [fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/)

Comment: So I believe the feature you're referring to is [Following TCP Streams](http://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChAdvFollowTCPSection.html); I'm wondering if you know of a way to display this on an ongoing basis, rather than having to find each new initial packet for each cycle?  In my mind's eye, I was hoping for a way to just keep a window open w/ the latest request/response in it...

Comment: The issue with fiddler is that I have an external device (not my computer) that's communicating with the internet server.  Fiddler seems to only like to analyze traffic from my machine.  I suppose it might do the right thing with my computer acting as the gateway, so I'll try that as well...

Comment: You can run fiddler as a local proxy on your computer. I usually have it running locally then tell my web browser to use it as a proxy server, then fiddler then displays what's happening in real time. I know that's not exactly what you're talking about, but the principle is the same. *edit* Just re-read your comment - yes, you'd have to configure your embedded device to use fiddler as the proxy.

Comment: Yes, follow TCP stream is what I'm talking about. I've only ever used it retrospectively once a packet capture has completed. I can imagine it would be tricky to do in real time, especially if your device is not tuned to re-use existing TCP connections.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with [**Wireshark**](http://www.wireshark.org/).  There are filters you can use to focus on HTTP traffic specifically.  That coupled with source / destination filters will let you see the request / response chain.

I'm also a fan of [**Webscarab**](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_WebScarab_Project) which is a java based proxy.